Angular application deployed to IIS virtual directory is looking for main.js in root
My angular application that runs locally with no problems. It is deployed to IIS through Azure Devops Pipelines. Once deployed, I am getting a 404 error where main.js is not found.  The application is looking for https://<root>/main.js
when it should be looking for https://<root>/<virtual>/main.js.  How is the target directory for main.js determined in IIS for angular applications?
Things I've tried:

I removed the webDAV module from web.config
Added the http calls to web.config for (GET, POST, etc...)
Compared deployment process and details with a working application. Both were the same.


This is expected. When you host an Angular web app on any web server (IIS or not) not as a site of its own but under a site, you need to adjust the base URL. That's in Angular documentation and search engines can tell you more.

Can you share more details about the Azure DevOps Pipeline?

Try change the base href in index.html as `<base href='/">
